# Export a single function in functional component Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-functional-component

I have a function that checks user data to login and delete cache when user clicks logout button i want the logout button in another component so i tried the export command to export that particular function but i couldn't able to do that ill upload my code here kindly help

React Code:

```
 import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import axios from 'axios';
import Login from './new'
export function Logout (props) {
  const { screen, setScreen } = props;

  const deleteCookie = async () => {
    try {
      await axios.get('/clear-cookie');
      setScreen('auth');
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
       <button class="btn btn-secondary"onClick={deleteCookie} style={{marginTop:'10px'}}>Logout</button>         
    </div>
  );
}

export function View (props) {
  const { screen, setScreen } = props;

  const [data, setData] = useState();

  const deleteCookie = async () => {
    try {
      await axios.get('/clear-cookie');
      setScreen('auth');
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };

  const getData = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get('/home');
      console.log(res.data)
      setData(res.data);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
     
      <p>{data}</p>
     <Login />
     {/*      <button class="btn btn-secondary"onClick={deleteCookie} style={{marginTop:'10px'}}>Logout</button>         */ } 
    </div>
  );
}

function Apps() {

  const [screen, setScreen] = useState('auth');
  const [username, setUsername] = useState();
  const [password, setPassword] = useState();

  const auth = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get('/authenticate', { auth: { username, password } });

      if (res.data.screen !== undefined) {
        setScreen(res.data.screen);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };

  const readCookie = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get('/read-cookie');
      
      if (res.data.screen !== undefined) {
        setScreen(res.data.screen);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      setScreen('auth');
      console.log(e);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    readCookie();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="col-10" >
      {screen === 'auth'
        ?  <Form className="Login form " style={{paddingTop:'3%',paddingLeft:'25%',width:'80%', paddingRight:'25%'}} >
        <Form.Group size="lg" controlId="email">
          <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            autoFocus
            type="text"
            
            onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
          />
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group size="lg" controlId="password">
          <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            type="password"
            value={password}
            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          />
        </Form.Group>
        <Button block size="lg" type="submit" onClick={auth}>
          Login
        </Button>
      </Form>
      :<div> <View screen={screen} setScreen={setScreen} />
      <Logout screen={screen} setScreen={setScreen} />
      </div>
      }
      
     
    </div>
  );
}

export default Apps;
```

I want to export the "deleteCookie" function so i can use the logout function there kindly help me with this

Comment: extract out logic in redux dispatch functions

Comment: You could use `React.Context` or pass down the `deleteCookie` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new `component` for `Logout` and use in many place. As the logout button only needs `deleteCookie` function so `deleteCookie` function should be in `Logout` Component like below:

```
export function Logout (props) {
  const { screen, setScreen } = props;

  const deleteCookie = async () => {
    try {
      await axios.get('/clear-cookie');
      setScreen('auth');
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
       <button class="btn btn-secondary"onClick={deleteCookie} style={{marginTop:'10px'}}>Logout</button>         
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: good idea bro but it doesn't work because there is setScreen('auth') function that has been used in another function. i updated my full code above kindly see and give suggestion

Comment: You can pass `setScreen` into `logout component` as you passed it already in `View component`

Comment: i tried but it doesn't work. i exported the logout component and import (import {Logout} from './file') in return function i add <Logout /> it works and show the Logout button but when i click that it doesn't work

Comment: what was the error?

Comment: TypeError: setScreen is not a function

Comment: you already passed `setScreen` into `View Component` it should work. if not can you please prepare `codesandbox` so that I can review

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239384/discussion-between-karthikeyan-m-and-khabir).